# Arduino uno toggle switch help

Tags: arduino-uno

I am building a box that will start a genset. It has two buttons, run and stop.
I would like button run to be able to start (and remain constant) until pressed a second time, I have sussed this bit so far, but this is where I get stuck.
I would like the stop button to only stop the the engine (as a single function)
So my question is how do I integrate the second button (stop) to carry out this one task?

```
int LEDYelState=0;
int LEDRedState=0;
int LEDGrnState=0;
int RELAYRedState=0;
int RELAYYelState=0;
int RELAYGrnState=0;
int LEDRedPin=10;
int LEDYelPin=9;
int LEDGrnPin=8;
int RELAYRedPin=7;
int RELAYYelPin=6;
int RELAYGrnPin=5;
int buttonPin=13;
int buttonNew;
int buttonOld=1;
int dt=100;
int buttonOff;
int buttonPinOff=12;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(LEDRedPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
pinMode (LEDYelPin,OUTPUT);
pinMode (LEDGrnPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode (RELAYRedPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode (RELAYYelPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode (RELAYGrnPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode (buttonPinOff, INPUT);
}
void loop() {
buttonNew=digitalRead(buttonPin);
buttonOff=digitalRead(buttonPin);
if(buttonOld==0 && buttonNew==1){
  if (LEDRedState==0){
    digitalWrite(LEDRedPin,HIGH);
    LEDRedState=1;
    digitalWrite(RELAYRedPin,LOW);
    RELAYRedState=1;

    digitalWrite(LEDYelPin, HIGH);
    LEDYelState=1;
    digitalWrite(RELAYYelPin, LOW);
    RELAYYelState=1;
    delay (8000);
    digitalWrite(LEDYelPin,LOW);
    digitalWrite(RELAYYelPin,HIGH);

    digitalWrite (LEDGrnPin,HIGH);
    LEDGrnState=1;
    digitalWrite (RELAYGrnPin, LOW);
    RELAYGrnState=1;
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite  (LEDGrnPin,LOW);
    digitalWrite (RELAYGrnPin,HIGH);
    RELAYGrnState=1;
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(LEDRedPin, LOW);
    LEDRedState=0;
    digitalWrite(RELAYRedPin, HIGH);
    RELAYRedState=0;
    digitalWrite(LEDYelPin,LOW);
    LEDYelState=0;


  }
}
buttonOld=buttonNew;
delay(dt);


}
```

Comment: separate the motor run function from the button press function .... declare a boolean variable ... name it `run` for example ... when it is true, then the engine runs ... when it is false, then the engine stops ... if you press start, then make `run` true ... if you press start again, then make `run` false .... when you press stop, then make `run` false

Comment: Could you give me some code that I can see for example that might work ? 

Cheers Bryan

Answer (score 1):

A general hint first: indent your code correctly. It makes it much easier to read and easier to spot logical errors.

Another improvement would be to name the pins with the same names as you name them when explaining the problem to us. I expected to find a `int buttonRunPin` and `int buttonStopPin`.

The first issue I see is:

```
buttonNew=digitalRead(buttonPin);
buttonOff=digitalRead(buttonPin);
```

This reads the same button twice. You probably wanted to read two different buttons: the "run" button and the "stop" button.

The next issue I see is:

```
delay(8000);
delay(2000);
```

During these 10 seconds, you can press and let go the button many times. But since there is no `digitalRead()` during that time, the button press will not be recognized.

The same applies to

```
int dt=100;
delay(dt);
```

If you press the button within these 100 ms, it will not be noticed.

Unfortunately, to fix that, you need to learn a completely new concept: [interrupts](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/). And even worse, not all pins support interrupts. On the Arduino Uno, it's only pin 2 and pin 3, which means you would need to change your hardware setup (because you use pin 12 and 13). Put both buttons from the pin to ground, so that it closes when pushed.

You would then prepare the interrupt in the `setup()` routine:

```
pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonPin), toggleRun, CHANGE);
pinMode(buttonPinOff, INPUT_PULLUP);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonPinOff), toggleStopped, CHANGE);
```

You also define global variables for the state of the buttons:

```
volatile bool running = false;
volatile bool stopped = false;
```

`volatile` is needed here to prevent the compiler from optimizing too much. The compiler does not know about the interrupts and thus can't know when the variable changes.

Next, you need two methods that are being executed whenever an interrupt occurs, i.e. you press a button:

```
void toggleRun() {
    running = !running;
}
void toggleStopped() {
    stopped = !stopped;
}
```

Note: the above `x = !x;` pattern is a short and efficient form of

```
if (x == false) {
    x = true;
}
else if (x == true) {
   x = false;
}
```

Once you have all that, you don't need the two `digitalRead()`s any more.

I'm afraid I haven't understood what your code's supposed to do. You have a lot of state variables that seem to have no use and especially they don't correspond to the motors. E.g. once `RELAYGrnState` is set to 1, it never changes back to 0.

This is what I have in the end:

```
int LEDYelState=0;
int LEDRedState=0;
int LEDGrnState=0;
int RELAYRedState=0;
int RELAYYelState=0;
int RELAYGrnState=0;
int LEDRedPin=10;
int LEDYelPin=9;
int LEDGrnPin=8;
int RELAYRedPin=7;
int RELAYYelPin=6;
int RELAYGrnPin=5;
int buttonPin=13;
int buttonNew;
int buttonOld=1;
int dt=100;
int buttonOff;
int buttonPinOff=12;

volatile bool running = false;
void toggleRun() {
    running = !running;
}

volatile bool stopped = false;
void toggleStopped() {
    stopped = !stopped;
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LEDRedPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (LEDYelPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode (LEDGrnPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (RELAYRedPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (RELAYYelPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (RELAYGrnPin, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonPin), toggleRun, CHANGE);
  pinMode(buttonPinOff, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonPinOff), toggleStopped, CHANGE);
}

void doSomething() {
  digitalWrite(LEDRedPin,HIGH);   // red LED is on
  LEDRedState=1;
  digitalWrite(RELAYRedPin,LOW);  // red motor off? others unclear
  RELAYRedState=1;

  digitalWrite(LEDYelPin, HIGH);  // yellow LED and red LED are on
  LEDYelState=1;
  digitalWrite(RELAYYelPin, LOW);  // yellow motor off?
  RELAYYelState=1;
  delay (8000);
  digitalWrite(LEDYelPin,LOW);     // red LED on
  digitalWrite(RELAYYelPin,HIGH);  // yellow motor on

  digitalWrite (LEDGrnPin,HIGH);  // red and green LED are on
  LEDGrnState=1;
  digitalWrite (RELAYGrnPin, LOW);  // green motor off
  RELAYGrnState=1;
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite  (LEDGrnPin,LOW);    // red LED on
  digitalWrite (RELAYGrnPin,HIGH);  // green motor on
  RELAYGrnState=1;
}

void doLess() {
  digitalWrite(LEDRedPin, LOW);     // red LED off
  LEDRedState=0;
  digitalWrite(RELAYRedPin, HIGH);  // red motor on
  RELAYRedState=0;
  digitalWrite(LEDYelPin,LOW);      // yellow LED off
  LEDYelState=0;
}

void loop() {
  if(running){
    if (!stopped){
      doSomething();
    }
    else{
      doLess();
    }
  }
  delay(dt);
}
```

Comment: I’ve taken that all on board, thank you, now I’ll try to get to grips with your advise ..... thanks again